# Jquery focus/outfocus on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck here. I need to be able to do a keypress on one field, focus on another textarea to trigger a keypress event, then focus back on the original field. Here is [my semi-working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3E9mG/1/)

Here is the code:

```
$('.editor').keyup(function () {
    //console.log($('#purpose').val());                                                                                           
    $('#purpose').trigger('keyup');
});

$('#purpose').bind('keyup propertychange', function (e) {
    //console.log(e);                                                                                                               
    $("#purpose").focus();
    $("#purpose").val($('#purpose-editor').val());
    console.log($("#purpose").val());
    $('#purpose-editior').trigger('input');
});

$('#purpose-editor').bind('input propertychange', function (i) {
    console.log(i);
    $('#purpose-editor').focus();
});
```

I can type in on the top field and focus on the second field, however I cannot focus back on the original field. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why focus on the second editor? If you remove the `$("#purpose").focus();` it works fine, and since you want to remove that focus almost instantly, does this really need to be there?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why does the first `textarea` in your Fiddle have an attribute `contenteditable`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of focusing each time, you could just try this:

```
$('#purpose-editor').keyup(function() {
    $('#purpose').val($('#purpose-editor').val()); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3E9mG/2/

Comment: I wish it was that simple. :( Unfortunately, I need to focus on the field to trigger a keydown event. Unless I focus on the second field, the keydown event is now honored.